# Synonyms for "get out of doing something"

Tags: synonyms, british-english

I would like to know some synonyms or phrases, or just other ways of expressing getting out of doing something, as in avoiding doing something.

Comment: Do you mean "avoiding doing something"? Can you supply a sample sentence showing how the phrase might be used?

Comment: I don't understand the question. *He got his way out of doing the job* doesn't sound like something any native speaker would be likely to say in any context. Perhaps you meant to say *He got out of doing the job* - he arranged things (often by implication using questionable methods) so he didn't have to do it. Please clarify.

Comment: with confusion in the question I rolled back my edit ... and will await OP response and community action.

Comment: "Get out of doing something"... like paying taxes? That might be fraud. Get out of my responsibility to support my child, that might be criminal negligence.

Comment: @Zebrafish  Wow.  Somone asks about not doing something and you jump to tax evasion and felony offenses.  Who do you work with?  :-)

Comment: @m_a_s Hehe, "Getting out of doing something" stirs my imagination. I'm still waiting for their clarification.

Comment: *Weasel* one's way out?

Comment: still no clarification from OP thus answers may be 'shooting in the dark'.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but now you pose 2 questions. Edit to a single question like the 1st:  "Synonyms for "get out of doing something". You can ask the 2nd by asking another separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the exact context "evade" may be the best word:
You can "evade paying your taxes" and you can "evade issues" that you rather not deal with.

If you are avoiding a simple task "dodge" may be the better word:
"He dodged the task of painting a fence by...."